# How can I randomize database rows if i am using mysql objects - codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, shuffle

My model returns data as mysql objects:

`return $q->result();`

Now, I want to shuffle/randomize the data and send it to the view file. But when I use the `shuffle($data)` on the object, it doesn't work, gives out an error. I guess, it will only work if my model returns an array.

Is there any way I can shuffle/randomize the data without converting it to an array, or without making the model return an array.

Comment: It might be efficient to actually show the error?

Comment: `Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Message is displayed in the view, where I use the foreach to loop through the shuffled result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you thought about add `$this->db->order_by('id', 'random');` when generating the query? The first parameter is the field name and the second the order (possible values are "asc", "desc", and "random"). Have a look at the [`order_by`](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html) function for more information.

**EDIT**:

Alternatively, you could use `result_array()` instead of `results()`. Here's an example:

```
// PHP5
$shuffled_result = $this->db->get('table')->result_array();
shuffle($shuffled_result);

// PHP4
$query = $this->db->get('table');
$shuffled_result = $query->result_array();
shuffle($shuffled_result);
```

Comment: Think this is the same as mentioned by flykobe.

Comment: More or less. This is the CodeIgniter way of doing it while his is the MySQL way of doing it. When using CodeIgniter, you should try to avoid writing your own SQL and use the functions that CodeIgniter provides. My solution is preferable if you're using CodeIgniter.

Comment: I've updated my code above to include a version that uses shuffle instead of ordering in SQL.

Comment: Yes, thanks. Looks like I will have to do it this way rather than using `$query->result()`. But I prefer to return out the rows as `echo $data->row_name` as opposed to `echo $data['row_name']`.

Comment: @Damchey - If you add a `$data = (object)$data;`, it will convert the array into an object and you'll be able to use $data->row_name.

Comment: @Francois. I did the following:

`$result = $q->result_array();`

`$shuffled_result = shuffle($result);`

`$shuffled_result = (object)$shuffled_result;`

`return $shuffled_result;`

And in the view file, I displayed it using `echo $data->row_name` and it gives out the following error:

`Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: @Damchey - That's not quite how that works... You'll have to return the array but in the `foreach` loop where you used to loop through the rows, that's where you want to use `$row = (array)$row;`. You don't want to do it on the `$shuffled_results` array.

Answer (score 1):

Objects do not have any explicit order of properties. You should be using an array if you require ordering.

Comment: @Damchey I generally use an array with associative array members myself, but an object for rows would be fine too.

Answer (score 0):

Well make you model to return the mysql data as array (give me the code if you don't know how) and from then you can use to shuffle the array with [Shuffle function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php)

I don't think you can shuffle the data base it self with query or something

Comment: I can use `$query->result_array()` to return an array, but I have been using `$query->result()` to return so far, and I want to keep it consistent. So was wondering if there was any way to randomize the objects. Now I think I should convert all my models to return array instead of objects.

Answer (score 0):

In mysql, you can order rows with order by rand(), like this:

```
select product_id  from product order by rand() limit 10;
```

so, you can get appropriate number of rows you want.

**EDIT:**

@Damchey you're right. If the table is bigger, than the rand() function will be slow. But every time, how many rows you select? 
So, Maybe you can get a random offset in php, and sql will like this:

```
select product_id  from product offset $random_offset limit 10
```

Although, the order of product_id is same, but offset is different, so if your table is big, than everytime you can get different rows.
And make sure, your offset if not bigger than rows_total - limit_num .

Comment: Yes true, but I don't want to use MySQL to randomize the rows, as I believe its not very efficient, and worsens as number of rows in the table increases.